# jQuery scroll on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to set up a simple chat system with `jQuery` / `Ajax`, but I'm having a strange behaviour with the scroll part. When I post something, or when I receive something, the scroll goes up instead of going down as requestes. Here's the code :

```
    $('form[name="iview-messages-chat"]').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {};
        data.msg = $('textarea', this).val();
        data.time = $('#iview-messages-pane .iview-messages-item:last').attr('data-time');
        data.uid = $('input[name="uid"]', this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php?page=messages&action=send',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index,value) {
                var nm = '<div class="clearfix iview-messages-item" style="height:auto;min-height:60px;width:730px;margin:0;" data-cid="'+value.id+'" data-time="'+value.time+'">';
                nm += '<img style="margin-top: 5px;" src="'+value.picture+'" />';
                nm += '<div class="iview-messages-item-info" style="width:630px;">';
                nm += '<div class="iview-messages-item-info-row" style="width:inherit;">';
                nm += '<a href="'+value.profile+'">'+value.first_name+' '+value.last_name+'</a>';
                nm += '<span style="float:right;font-size:11px;">'+value.elapsed_time+'</span>';
                nm += '</div>';
                nm += '<div class="iview-messages-item-info-row">';
                nm += '<span>'+value.content+'</span>';
                nm += '</div>';
                nm += '</div>';
                nm += '</div>';
                $('#iview-messages-pane').append(nm);
            });

            $('form[name="iview-messages-chat"] textarea').val('');
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(data))
            {
                $('#iview-messages-pane').animate({scrollTop: $('#iview-messages-pane').height()}, 800);
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('error');
        });

        return false;
    });
```

**markup**

```
div id="iview-messages-pane">
<div id="iview-messages-pane-handler" class="clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix iview-messages-item" style="height:auto;min-height:60px;width:730px;margin:0;" data-cid="36" data-time="1340591805">
        <img style="margin-top: 5px;" src="http://myiview.me/upload/1/4fda8a23cb3c3_200_200.jpg" />
        <div class="iview-messages-item-info" style="width:630px;">
            <div class="iview-messages-item-info-row" style="width:inherit;">
                <a href="http://myiview.me/index.php?page=profile&uid=1">Filipe Matias</a>
                <span style="float:right;font-size:11px;">19 hours ago</span>
            </div>
            <div class="iview-messages-item-info-row">
                <span>Hmmmmmm yeeelloowww!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any tips?

Comment: First, I'd do a `console.log($('#iview-messages-pane').height());` near the `animate` call and see if it seems reasonable.

Comment: You should also `console.log($('#iview-messages-pane').scrollTop());` to get the current scroll value.

Comment: It scrolls all the way down at the page load, but when the script checks for new messages this is the result : `height: 510, scroll : 710`. When this occurs, the scroll goes almost all the way up. I should probably set a inner container for `#iview-messages-pane`

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you are scrolling the wrong element. Please include example markup for `#iview-messages-pane` and its parent. Is `#iview-messages-pane` really the container that is scrolling?

Comment: so, the height is the height of the container, not the total height of the contents. Try sabithpocker's answer below.

Comment: Tried with what I had, with a inner container and calculating the total height. None of them worked.

Comment: Create a fiddle with isolated case, we might feel easy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the hight is not getting the height you expect as @lbstr pointed out

```
$('#iview-messages-pane')
    .animate({
        scrollTop: (function(){
            var combinedHeightOfChildren = 0;
            $('#iview-messages-pane').children().each(function(){
                combinedHeightOfChildren += $(this).outerHeight();
            });
            return combinedHeightOfChildren - $('#iview-messages-pane').height();
        })(); // execute the function immediately
    }, 800);
```

As per @lbstr suggession:
The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area so when fully scrolled down the height of the messagespane is visible, hidden part is

```
combinedHeightOfChildren - $('#iview-messages-pane').height();
```

so it should return

```
return combinedHeightOfChildren - $('#iview-messages-pane').height();
```

There wont be a visible error as we cannot scroll further, just made this sepertate so that other users can follow what happened.

http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/sgu6p/ here is a fiddle showing the working

http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/sgu6p/1/ fiddle with add + scroll!!

Comment: technically, it should be `return combinedHeightOfChildren - $('#iview-messages-pane').height();`. +1 anyway, because you are right: the height of the container will always be the same, but the combined height of its children won't be, and thats what you need to check against.

Comment: @lbstr the height of a child handler inside the container is always different. Also, the code doesn't work at all.

Comment: @sabithpocker -- a couple other edits: you need to initalize `var combinedHeightOfChildren = 0;`. Also, you have to execute that function: `{scrollTop: (function(){...})()}` for it to work.

Comment: @yoda Please add HTML/CSS you are using or create a js fiddle

Comment: @sabithpocker you didn't quite do the function bit correctly. I submitted an edit which will need to be reviewed, but you need to do `{scrollTop: (function(){...})()}` and remove the extra `()` that you added after the `each` function.

Comment: @sabithpocker jsfiddle.net/mYvQa

Comment: It's working now. The final `()` update did what was missing. Thanks!